# Need to split string with repeated words in seperate row in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi i need help in splitting column into rows where ever repeated words are coming.

```
 p_id        Name

 92222       MCD45-Quantum Red<REF ID="1552" TYPE="trademark"/>
             TRI-TAG<REF ID="4684" TYPE="trademark"/>
```

i want to break into rows where  TYPE="trademark" is coming 
  for ex :

```
p_id           Name 

92222          MCD45-Quantum Red<REF ID="1552" TYPE="trademark"/>
92222          TRI-TAG<REF ID="4684" TYPE="trademark"/>
```

It is dynamic and not known that how many times REF ID will come in column 
 string.for checking that i have used code :

```
regexp_count(name,'trademark') > 1
```

Can you please suggest how to do this.

Comment: Multiple methods in those linked questions - just change the delimiter.

Comment: yes correct but i am finding difficult in finding delimiter in current situation

Comment: Use `TYPE="trademark"/>` as the delimiter and then append it back onto the string?